# What controls the generation of window borders? (MATE)

Tags: xorg, window-manager, customization, search

What I'm looking for is what controls window borders; specifically what actually defines what goes where (as in, the program that says the bottom bar goes at the bottom, not the side or what keeps the title bar on top).

I have been looking through files and cannot decide whether it is the window manager that controls this (this would be logical as it is the window MANAGER after all). However, it could also be the os itself or Xorg or perhaps something completely different. What I am looking for is the specific program that controls the generation of window borders so that I can narrow down my search. (My goal with this is to find the code that dictates this mapping so that I can attempt to change it)

If anyone has even a rough idea as to where I ought to continue my search I would be very thankful!

Comment: depends on your desktop environment, mate, gnome use gtk & gtk3. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/

Comment: I'm using MATE so I've been looking around for files to do with MATE, marco and xorg but most of them contain several hundred lines of code so looking through them all would take too much time.

Comment: I think gtkwindow is what you want. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html programs with gtk frontends, have a widget, with a reference to functions in the gtkwindow widget. if you want to change default behaviour for all the programs on the system, perhaps a theme could do it. Im a newb for themes though.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll look into the themes in more detail and see if I come up with something.